# UML class Diagram - Player Playing Game

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am making a simple game with Users, where they can login to there account and can play games to try and beat there own high scores.  I have a 'Player Class' who then Chooses which game they want to play.  Is there a way to represent that a Player can be anonymous when playing the game?

Would the correct way to do this be through Aggregation?

Diagram Attached. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a lot of different behavior, i would use generalization (just like you did with Game and Board game): Player (anonymous) becomes the superclass, and Registered Player (not anonymous) becomes the subclass. In that way a registered player can do the same and more than a normal player, like for instance looking up his results of the past, see his login times and so on....